# Polars dataframe doesn't drop column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-polars

I have a function in a script that I am testing and the `df.drop()` function is not working as expected.

app.py

```
def area(df,value):
    df["area"] = df['geo'].apply(lambda row:to_area(row))
    df["area"] = df["area"].apply(lambda row: abs(row - mean))
    df = df.filter(pl.col("area") < value)
    df = df.drop("area")
    return df
```

test.py

```
def test():
    df = some df
    res = area(df,2)
    res_2 = area(df,4)
```

At res_2, I keep getting the "area" column back in the dataframe, which is causing me problems with type checking. Any ideas on what might be causing this? I know that using `df.clone()` works, but I don't understand what is causing this issue with how things are set up.

Comment: Try adding the ```inplace=True``` argument

Comment: Can you show a minimal example that reproduces this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try DataFrame.drop_in_place, instead of drop.
The function drops and returns the column specified. If you inspect the
df after calling drop_in_place you will notice it is gone.

[drop_in_place documentation](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.drop_in_place.html#polars.DataFrame.drop_in_place)

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "foo": [1, 2, 3],
        "bar": [6, 7, 8],
        "ham": ["a", "b", "c"],
    }
)
df.drop_in_place("ham")
shape: (3,)
Series: 'ham' [str]
[
    "a"
    "b"
    "c"
]

┌─────┬─────┐
│ foo ┆ bar │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 6   │
│ 2   ┆ 7   │
│ 3   ┆ 8   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Could you add a bit more details as the link might die at any time